# LIMIT Postgres DELETE

Tags: postgresql, limit, sql-delete

Simple DELETE with safety LIMIT throws a syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM system."products" LIMIT 1
```

> ERROR: Syntax ERROR at "LIMIT"
>
> SQL state: 42601

How do I limit the amount of rows to delete?

(PostgresSQL version 9.6)

Comment: Of course, LIMIT in any query makes much more sense when you have ORDER BY

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought my query is simple ANSI SQL working in all ANSI compatible systems

Comment: There is no `LIMIT` in ANSI SQL (not for DELETE, nor for any other SQL command)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `LIMIT` only in the `SELECT` statement.

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM system."products" WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM system."products" LIMIT 1)
```

Otherwise you can have something like this

```
DELETE FROM system."products" WHERE id bewteen ? and ?
```

Obviously this can work only if there is in your table an unique column (named `id` in my examples)!

Comment: `IN()` is evil, is there no other way?

Comment: @DanielW.: why do you think `IN ()` is evil - especially if it only contains a single value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my query contains more than one value, you are discussing things not related to the question

Comment: @DanielW.: then post the actual query. If you show us a (over) simplified problem, how do you expect to get an answer for the **real** problem

Comment: @DanielW. Has the table a primary key?

Comment: You can use a JOIN or a CTE instead of IN().

Comment: @DanielW. and for exactly that problem Renato has given you an answer.

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen Imagine I am writing software to detect corruption of data and deleting a limited amount of random (unpredicted) rows is exactly what I want to do. In MySQL, `IN()` should be avoided as much as possible in favour of `EXISTS()`, totally possible Postgres is doing a better job there than MySQL.

Comment: So while I am asking for a syntactical solution, you keep bashing my semantic intention.

Comment: this is not a solution if there is no unique column in the table

Comment: @DanielAlder, you're right, it needs an unique column. This was also a question I asked. Anyway ... edited!